# Not fullscreen scrollable activity

Tags: android, layout

How do I make this kind of popup activity that I can scroll to enlarge/kill? I know how to make the layout of a normal activity but I would like to add this feature if I can.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `BottomSheetBehavior`.

You can put your layouts in the main activity or use a fragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout...>
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout...">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar... />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_layout" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
        (desired view here)
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Read more:

- https://medium.com/@nullthemall/new-bottomsheet-caab21aff19b
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html

Comment: didn't know how it was called and it was very hard to find. Thank you.